# PersistableBundle pass values to service and retrieve

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-jobscheduler

I am using JobScheduler and able to run the scheduler.

Now I want to pass some values from my Activity to my Service class using PersistableBundle. Can someone guide how to pass the values and retrieve it? Here is the function in which I am trying to pass values.

```
private void constructJob(){
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, MyService.class));
PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
bundle.putInt("height",height);
bundle.putInt("width",width);
builder.setPeriodic(20000)
        .setExtras(bundle)
        .setPersisted(true);

mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Your `JobService` will be called with `onStartJob()`, being passed in a `JobParameters`. Call `getExtras()` on the `JobParameters` to get the `PersistableBundle` to read in the values:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    PersistableBundle pb=params.getExtras();

    // do good stuff
  }
```